# How to load complex columns in JSON file in ADF Data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, microsoft-azure-documentdb

I have a requirement to load a database table data into JSON format and there are total 4 column in database.
Column in database are like: ID,Name,Designation,AssignedID
The sample output in JSON file should be like this:

{"Employee"[{"id":value,"name":value:"designation":value,"Assignee"[{"assigneid":value1,"assigneid":value2,"assigneid":value3}]},
{"id":value,"name":value:"designation":value,"Assignee"[{"assigneid":value1,"assigneid":value2,"assigneid":value3}]}]}

the data has to grouped by on ID.
I am able to create a complex type column Employee and Assignee but for every id there can be multiple AssignedID. And in my output file instead of all AssignedID coming inside the single array  Assignee, they are coming as comma separated as a different row.

Can anyone please me on this. Let me know for any query.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to transform data into a complex form:

[image]

After reading data from the source, add a derived column with the expression as shown below:

[image]

And use the expression `@(assigneid=AssignedID)`.

This creates a complex type as the result.

Next, add an **Aggregate** activity with **Group By** `ID`, `Name`, and `Designation` according to your requirement, and aggregate on `Assignee` with the expression:

`collect(Assignee)`

[image]

Then, add a sink. This gives you the result as shown below:

```json
{"ID":"1234","Name":"value","Designation":"value","Assignee":[{"assigneid":"value1"},{"assigneid":"value2"},{"assigneid":"value3"}]}
{"ID":"567","Name":"value","Designation":"value","Assignee":[{"assigneid":"value1"},{"assigneid":"value2"},{"assigneid":"value3"}]}
```

To make it an array of objects, you need to use **CopyActivity** by selecting the `File pattern` as **Array of objects**.

[image]

This gives the result as shown below:

```json
[{"ID":"1234","Name":"value","Designation":"value","Assignee":[{"assigneid":"value1"},{"assigneid":"value2"},{"assigneid":"value3"}]}
,{"ID":"567","Name":"value","Designation":"value","Assignee":[{"assigneid":"value1"},{"assigneid":"value2"},{"assigneid":"value3"}]}
]
```

However, if you want all rows to be in the `Employee` field, it will give you values for each row and not all in a single field.

I used the expression below in one more derived column with the name `Employee`:

```json
@(id=ID,
name=Name,
designation=Designation,
Assignee=Assignee)
```

Result:

[image]

So, I recommend using the sink to write the whole column rather than a single field, and then using the copy activity to make it an array of objects.

Comment: I tried in similar way and data is coming file till last second stage, but even if using the copy activity it is still proving the output as an array of Assignid. I created both the derived column inside data flow and taking output as single column.

Comment: Are you using this expression `@(assigneid=AssignedID)` in derived column named `Assignee`.

Comment: See the second image in my post

Comment: Till sink, my output is coming just like yours, but if I need to add this whole object inside an Employee array then should I use the derived and agg activity again in Dataflow?

Comment: Even that does work. It just create array around Employee values with all the rows.

Comment: can you show me the source of copy activity. it should be the sink output of dataflow, but when I am doing that, it gives error while reading the file.

Comment: In sink you write as single file and select that file in source of copy activity as json dataset.

Comment: in your final last result, you are getting Employee with every row, but if you see in my requirement Employee is not getting repeated. so, inside Employee type array we are loading the objects. Can you help me to get this   {"Employee"[{"id":value,"name":value:"designation":value,"Assignee"[{"assigneid":value1,"assigneid":value2,"assigneid":value3}]}, {"id":value,"name":value:"designation":value,"Assignee"[{"assigneid":value1,"assigneid":value2,"assigneid":value3}]}]}

Comment: with using dataflow not possible even if you do aggregate. So best way is to use notebook activity with pyspark code for transformation. this makes lot easier.